# php image and text upload not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to upload some information to a database using php, I have been able to upload images and text seperatly but not together (my goal). For some reason the image will go into the specified folder however the info wont be put into the database for some reason and keeps throwing me the "failed" else statement! I'm obviously new to php and help would be much appreciated!! Here is my php code:

```html
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['profileup'];
            
            $fileName = $_FILES['profileup']['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['profileup']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['profileup']['size'];
            $fileError = $_FILES['profileup']['error'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['profileup']['type'];
            $Newname = $fileName;
            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

            if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){

                if ($fileError === 0){

                    if ($fileSize < 10000000000){
                        $filedest = 'postimages/'.$Newname;
                        $username = $_SESSION[user];
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $filedest);               
                        header("Location: ../UserProfile.php?suc");
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (img, ext) VALUES ('$filedest', '$fileActualExt');";
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                        if($result !== false) {
                            exit;
                        }else{
                            echo "fail";
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "your file was to big";
                    }

                }else{
                    echo "There was an error uploading your file";
                }

            }else{
                echo "you cant upload files of this type";
            }
    }else{
        header("Location: ../UserProfileSetting.php?fail");
    }    
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Move `header("Location: ../UserProfile.php?suc");` inside `if($result !== false){...}` block.

Comment: thanks for the sugestions, but still seems to be throwing the errror

Comment: You can also do `echo mysqli_error($conn);` right after `mysqli_query(..)` to see what error is happening.

Comment: @tadman procedural vs object-oriented mysqli are strongly a matter of personal preference. I prefer procedural over object-oriented mysqli to limit the situations where a method doesn't exist due to poor edge case handling. The thing I like about mysqli is it has support for a style similar to the old mysql_* functions, which is the way my brain thinks in certain scenarios. If I want to embrace procedural style, I prefer using PDO so it's easy to swap between database option. Nothing wrong with either, it's the same extension.

Comment: @Ultimater It's not strongly personal. By any measure the OO form is shorter, and more importantly, it's absolutely impossible to confuse with `mysql_query`. The old style is actually inherited from `mysql_query` which is *directly* copied from the ugly, low-level C library from the 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Move your redirection part after you complete your insert query.
The code below will do your trick.
The problem is you r redirecting your page before executing your insert query. 
       if ($fileSize < 10000000000){
                                $filedest = 'postimages/'.$Newname;
                                $username = $_SESSION[user];
                                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $filedest);               
                                $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (img, ext) VALUES ('$filedest', '$fileActualExt');";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                if($result !== false) {
                                    header("Location: ../UserProfile.php?suc");
                                }else{
                                    echo "fail";
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo "your file was to big";
                            }
```